# Run a command on a spawned shell

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to automate a process (all the commands are sent via a simple shell) and I encountered the next issue: I execute a C file that spawns a shell (it is a local exploit, [http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2015/CVE-2015-1328.html](http://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/2015/CVE-2015-1328.html) once you run it, a  shell with root privileges is spawned in the current shell).

What I want is a method to run a command ("id") inside that shell and get back its output.

Something like:

1. before exploit: "uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)"
2. after exploit "uid=9(root)....."

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Check `expect`, it can probably do what you want.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. 
expect -c 'set timeout -1; spawn ./xxxx; expect "creating"; send -- "id\r"; expect "uid"'
Did the job